# Overlapping Circles Area

Tags: geometry, circles, pi, area

I have searched but could not find the exact question.

Two circles with radii 5 intersect such that the center of one circle lies on the circumference of another. What is the area of the overlapping region in terms of pi?

Comment: Do you know what shape the intersecting circle-edge points form with either of the circle centers?

Comment: If you were allowed, I just computed an appropriate integration to get $50 \left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \right) \approx 30.7092$ for comparison at least. Total area of one circle being about 78.5398, and a bit more than twice the desired area, my solution seems pretty feasible.

Comment: Note that on that link [Area of intersection between two circles](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402858/area-of-intersection-between-two-circles), the geometric answer by Ilya Melamed corresponds to my calculus. He says $r^2\left( \frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)$, and that corresponds to my integral.