# Circles Of Descartes

Tags: geometry

Insired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022185/area-of-figure-in-sector-of-intersecting-circles/),

[image]

where the objective is to calculate the shaded area in the above diagram, I noticed that the inscribed circle has the following relation to the circles it rests on

\begin{align}
&\sqrt{1-\left(x\pm\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\\
&\sqrt{\frac{1}{16}-\left(x\pm\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}\\
&\pm\sqrt{c^2-x^2}+c\sqrt{\frac{1}{2 c}+1}\\
\end{align}

with the centre of the circle at

\begin{align}
\left\{0,\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{c}+2}{\left(\frac{1}{c}+4\right)^2}} \left(\frac{1}{c}+4\right) \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}
\end{align}

given in cartesian cordinates, where the $c=\dfrac{3}{10}$ in the first diagram shown. For varying $c$, the plot looks like this:

[image]

This relation then, can be used as the beginnings of a bit of circle packing:

[image]

[image]

though the exact values of $c$ here are estimated, and as yet, unknown.

I can't really describe how I found this relation though, other than by chance, and looking at number patterns. Why does this work, and what are the values of $c$ as per [the circles of Descartes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7giWf.gif) (shown below) for the infinite packing? Can this same approach be extended to filling all of the gaps?

[image]

(Image from Wolfram Demonstrations, by Ed Pegg Jr)