# how to find the space of one circle minus the second circle

Tags: circles

I got two circles c1 and c2 with the same radius and different center. The two circles overlapped. How to calculate the space in C1 without the overlapped section with C2.

Comment: See if [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) is helpful.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402858/area-of-intersection-between-two-circles

Comment: I need opposite ! the space on circle one despite of overlapped space with circle 2

Comment: @user1658028: Simply subtract the area of the intersection from the area of the first circle.

Comment: But to be clear, you cannot use directly the answers to the question @Fluffy12 linked, as that is the specific case where each circle passes through the other's center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

If $d$ is the distance between the centers of the two circles (of radius $R$) than the angle at center of one circle that subtend the arc between the common points is : 
$
\theta=2\arccos(d/2)
$

Now use this angle to find the area of the [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) as
$$
C=R^2(\theta -\sin \theta)/2
$$

and the area that you want is $A=\pi R^2 -2C$

Comment: Thanks in advance. This is great. Is it also possible to find the same result by using the distance of centers instead of angle calculation?

Comment: No. To calculate the area of a circular segment we need the angle.