# Finding the region bounded by a circle and rosetta leaf

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I want to find the following region:
$R$ is the region bounded by the circle of radius $a$ and and the center at the origin and the rosetta leaf $r=2a\cos(\theta)$ with $x \ge 0$ and $r \ge a$.

So, I draw the region. There are two parts,  one is above and the other one is below the $x-$axis. I try to write one integral and then multiply it by $2$ to find solution.

Here is what I wrote:

$\displaystyle 2\int_{0}^{\frac{arc\cos(1/2)}{2}} \int_a^{2a\cos(2\theta)}rdrd\theta$

Is it correct, any hints would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: In you question you ask about $r = 2a\cos\theta$, but in your integral you use the expression $2a\cos(2\theta)$. Is one of these a typo?

Comment: Where have you seen this strange name "Rosetta leaf" ?

Answer (score 1):

If the second curve has equation $r=2a\cos\theta$, it's a circle.
[image: Intersection of circles]
The two circles intersect when
$$
    2a \cos\theta = a \implies \cos\theta = \frac{1}{2} \implies \theta = \pm\frac{\pi}{3}
$$
Therefore the area of the region is
\begin{align*}
    \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \int_a^{2 a\cos\theta} r\,dr\,d\theta
    &= 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \int_a^{2 a\cos\theta} r\,dr\,d\theta \\
    &= \int_{0}^{\pi/3}\left. r^2 \right|_a^{2 a\cos\theta} \,d\theta \\
    &= \int_{0}^{\pi/3}\left(4a^2\cos^2\theta - a^2\right)\,d\theta \\
    &= a^2 \int_{0}^{\pi/3}\left(2(1+\cos2\theta) - 1\right)\,d\theta \\
    &= a^2 \int_{0}^{\pi/3}\left(1+2\cos2\theta\right)\,d\theta \\
    &= a^2 \left[\theta+\sin 2\theta\right]_{0}^{\pi/3}\\
    &= a^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

If the second curve has equation $r=2a\cos2\theta$, it's a *rose* of four leaves. 
[image: intersection of rose and circle] The curves intersect when
$$
    a = 2a \cos2 \theta \implies \cos2 \theta = \frac{1}{2}
$$
The portion in the right half-plane has three components.  Let's find the area of the largest component.  That is the portion with $-\frac{\pi}{6} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$.  Its area is
$$
    A = 2 \int_0^{\pi/6}\int_0^{2a\cos2 \theta} r\,dr\,d\theta
$$
Substituting $\phi = 2\theta$ and $d\phi = 2d\theta$ transforms this integral into the previous one.  So
$$
    A = \frac{1}{2}\cdot a^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
      = a^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)
$$

Comment: In the first case diameter is $2a$, not $3a$

Comment: In the first case of two intersecting circles I don't think the answer is right. I can't work out where you went wrong but https://math.stackexchange.com/a/402891/5011 shows the answer I get by a geometric approach (rather than using integrals).

Comment: @Narasimham: If you are talking about the graph then a = 1.5 in those graphs (I don't know why but it is).

Comment: Both circles need to be scaled down

Comment: @Chris Are we talking about the same region?  The linked question seems to ask about the region which is inside both circles.  As I read the OP's question it seems to ask about the region outside the center (blue) circle but inside the green circle.

Comment: @Narasimham: I used a Desmos applet with a parameter $a$.  For purposes of the diagram I set $a$ to be 1.5.  If I get a chance I'll redo it, display the parameter, and provide a link.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Ah yes, you may be right. My bad! I think I saw two intersecting circles and just assumed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the poor quality sketch. For a simple geometrical situation direct computation may be ok.

The "rosetta" or 2 leaved rose of two circles  passes through origin with center on x-axis. Due to equality of side and circle radius we have a regular hexagon.

[image]

The pointed areas between regular hexagon and circle have area

$$ A_{needle}=(\pi a^2- \frac{\sqrt3}{4} a^2 \cdot 6) \cdot \frac{1}{6}$$

Area above x-axis has areas as a semi-circle radius $a$ - sector area radius $a$ /6 - needle area

$$ A = 2 (\pi a^2/2 - \frac16 \cdot \pi a^2 - [\frac{\pi a^2}{6} -\frac{\sqrt3}{4} a^2])= \frac{\pi a^2}{3} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2} a^2 $$

after doubling it for required area.